# Test fails when run from rake, passes when run directly

Tags: ruby, rake

Running Ruby 1.9.3, when I run my test directly with ./test_mail.rb, it passes.  When I run it via 'rake test', it fails with

```
  1) Failure:
test_initialization(TC_Test_mail) [/Users/lcuff/Software_Realm/eco/etl  
/etl/etl_2.0/src/ruby/mail_processing/ruby_eco_classes/rake_example   
/test_mail.rb:13]:
Expected: "Hi Mom"
Actual: "No subject specified"
```

My class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class MyMail

  attr_reader :subject

  def initialize( mail)

    subject = mail.to_s[/Subject:.*\r?/]
    if subject.nil?
      subject = "No subject specified"
    else
      subject = subject.strip.gsub!(/Subject:\s/, '')
    end
    @subject = subject
  end
end
```

My test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'MyMail'

class  TC_Test_mail < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_initialization
    mock_mail = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock_mail.expect(:to_s, "Subject: Hi Mom\nDate 2014-04-01\n", [])
    the_mail = MyMail.new(mock_mail)
    assert_equal('Hi Mom', the_mail.subject )
    mock_mail.verify
  end
end
```

And the rakefile

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "test_*.rb"
end
```

Comment: Are there multiple tests run when you `rake`? If so, are they done in random order/the test in question isn't first?

Comment: There are multiple tests.  The test in question can run anywhere in the group.  It's the same if I change the pattern to only match the test in question.

Comment: The operating system you are using may be an important factor in this situation. `\r\n` is the line separator in windows, and `\n` is what's used in *nix. Strictly speaking the `'\r'` in your regex shouldn't match the `'\n'` in your test-data. There is some environmental factor causing this to be overlooked when executing from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that stands out for me here is the fact that you are using `'\n'` to delimit the different parameters in a single string.

Your regular expression is matching with: `/Subject:.*\r?/`

But you are passing in the string: `"Subject: Hi Mom\n`…

I don't know much about Rake specifically, but in my experience the way these tests get executed in a batch environment imposes slightly different environmental conditions, than when invoked directly.

Could be that when you are invoking from command-line the ruby regular expression engine knows that `'\r'` matches `'\n'`, but in the purer batch environment it doesn't do you this favour.

If you change your regex to `/Subject:.*[\r]?[\n]?/` you should see proper cross-platform operation.

In fact `/Subject:[^\r\n]*?/` might be neater.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> mail = "Subject: Hi Mom\nDate 2014-04-01\n"
=> "Subject: Hi Mom\nDate 2014-04-01\n"
irb(main):004:0> subject = mail.to_s[/Subject:[^\r]*/]
=> "Subject: Hi Mom\nDate 2014-04-01\n"
irb(main):005:0> subject = mail.to_s[/Subject:[^\r\n]*/]
=> "Subject: Hi Mom"
```